# Is it possible, to define multiple parameters for a Luis intent?

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-language-understanding

When Luis find and intent I would like to store different variables?, which I can use in the following process.

1. User asks a question to a dispatch bot
2. Luis defines intent
3. Based on intent, it gets the KBID (QnA), A teamID (MS teams), A URL (A Sharepoint site)
4. User receives an answer back from the dispatch bot in an adaptive card in teams

- Answer from KB (based on intent)
- Two buttons "Contact the team" (teamID which was found based on intent), "Visit teams site" (SharePoint URL which was found based on intent)

I did find whats to add QnA, Luis, file. But I cannot figure out how to link the teamID, the KB and the sharePoint URL, so when the user receives the answer the card had the correct answering text and two buttons which link to the right places. We could have a file of FB where we store for each expert team the QnA, TeamID and Site, so when Luis gets the intent, it can pass that information onto the card

Any ideas on if and how this could be achieved? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't completely follow what you are trying to do. Could you post a code snippet of what you have tried already? You can certainly use the utterance/intent to look up different things like a teamID but it depends on where you are getting that information from and what input you need to retrieve it.